# Inserting Tags into Searched String/String Case

Tags: php

I have a script that needs some refinement.  Essentially what it does is takes a string, then attempts to search for that within another string to insert some HTML around it for the purposes of highlighting.

Currently it looks like this:

```
$query = $_POST['$query'];
$searched = "New York Yankees in New York";

str_ireplace($query,"<span class='hilight'>".$query."</span>", $searched);
```

Now, it works, but it behaves oddly (predictably) when it comes to uppercase/lowercase.

Say $query = 'new'..  The returned string would be :

```
<span class='hilight'>new</span> York Yankees in <span class='hilight'>new</span> York.
```

How would you go about accomplishing the same thing without changing the case of the original searched string?

Comment: With regexps of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is using regular expressions and the [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function:

```
$query = 'new';
$searched = "New York Yankees in New York";
$r = preg_replace("/($query)/i", "<span class='hilight'>$1</span>", $searched);
echo'r is: ',$r;
```

So, main action here goes in [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace(
    // find substring `$query`, flag `i` means case-insensitive search
    "/($query)/i",
    // replace founded occurences with this string, `$1` here means the value of the founded substring (`new` or `New` or even `NEW`)
    "<span class='hilight'>$1</span>", 
    // string where to find
    $searched
);
```